# Manage /etc/hosts from menu bar

Tags: software-recommendation, menu-bar

Some years ago, I recall a menu bar application that would allow you to activate/de-activate host entries in /etc/hosts.

I can't seem to find it via google.  Anyone have recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a menu bar item, but [this preferences pane called Hosts](https://github.com/specialunderwear/Hosts.prefpane) is by far the best `/etc/hosts` manager I tried. And you can enable or disable entries easily.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Gas Mask](https://code.google.com/p/gmask/). It’s so useful!